# c#: Calculation inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops, calculation

I have to multiply numbers in the following order:
   ( 1 , 3*5, 5*7*9, 7*9*11*13, ...) until it reaches 11 values and I've used this code for it:

```
for (int t = 1; t <= 11; t++)
{
    for (int i = (2 * t) - 1; i <= (4 * t) - 3; i = i + 2) {
        result = result * i; 
    } 

}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

but each time it loops, it also multiplies with the previous result.
(ex: 1, 15, 4725, 42567525,...) 
How can I fix this?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do, can you try to give more explanation? (like expected behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset result after each step:

```
for (int t = 1; t <= 11; t++)
{
    result = 1;
    for (int i = (2 * t) - 1; i <= (4 * t) - 3; i = i + 2) {
        result = result * i; 
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Update: Here's a working example, just click run: https://repl.it/Nlab/1
Note that I initialized result as double because the numbers were getting to big for simple integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your printline must be inside the first **for** loop. At present it is working perfectly but the problem is you are not printing it at the right time

Your code should be :

```
    int result = 1;
    for (int t = 1; t <= 11; t++)
    {
        for (int i = (2 * t) - 1; i <= (4 * t) - 3; i = i + 2)
        {
            result = result * i; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

But I would recommend you to use **Int64** instead of **int** in case of *overflow*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var numbers =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 11)
        .Select(n =>
            Enumerable
                .Range(0, n)
                .Select(x => ((long)n + (long)x - 1L) * 2L + 1L)
                .Aggregate((x0, x1) => x0 * x1));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers));
```

That gives me:

```
1
15
315
9009
328185
14549535
760543875
45808142625
3124115327025
237984079323375
20028239096740875
```